# Can we make custom variables?

Tags: python, variables

i'm stuck on some coding and i tried many things like `lists`, `arrays`, `vars()` and many other things but none fit my problem:

i want to make "custom" variables
for example: we have var and we need 500 images of it and 12 categories, making it 6000 different versions we just can't put in
so we would have a for loop making each one of them and giving them a value
like `var_1_1 = 16`, `var_2_1 = 254`, `var_3_1...` `var_499_12 = 5`

i tried using `vars()`:

```
vars()[str("var_"+nb+"_"+cat)]
```

for some time it worked fine until i tried making a `var_x = Entry(window)` and using the `.get()` fuction which went downhill fast from here until i tried arrays and other things in a desperate motion

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary?

Comment: yup and i get this:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Utilisateur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Utilisateur/.PyCharmEdu2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_2.py", line 87, in cheezegrater
    print(button_offset[1][1].get())
KeyError: 1

Comment: What about creating own class and manipulate with getattr, setattr?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

If you have multiple values for the same purpose, you should put them in a list:

```
>>> spam = [1,2,3,4]
>>> print(spam)
[1,2,3,4]
>>> print(spam[0])
1
```

You can also nest lists like this:

```
my_list = []
for i in range(12):
     inner_list = []
     for j in range(500):
         inner_list.append("image " + str(j) + "," + str(i))
     my_list.append(inner_list)
print(my_list[5][32])
```

For more information about lists, see: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: sadly it doesn't work as i said before as it does this :    button_offset.insert[serie][id] = Entry(kanvas, width=10)
id= 1 serie= 1
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

i believe you are looking for a 2d array 
eg

```py
items = [[1,2],[5,6]]

# so then
print(items[0][1])
# would give 2
```

Comment: sadly it does'nt work for me as the thing itself crashes     button_offset.insert[serie][id] = Entry(kanvas, width=10)
id= 1 serie= 1
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: this doesn't work because you are trying to assign an index in a non existent object as button_offset_insert[serie] is not yet a list that must be initiated first

Answer (score 0):

If indexes are simple incrementing integers you can use multi-dimensional lists:

`x[0][0] = 16; x[0][1] = 254; ... x[11][498] = 5`

The convention in most languages is to have the last index vary the fastest.

Else you can use a dictionary to hold arbitrary string indexes.

A quick search turned up:
https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/CS152f17/Lists/NestedLists.html